# Android Change text ExoPlayer Default Receiver

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, chromecast, exoplayer, android-mediasession

I am using the exoPlayer cast extension for my application Android. And I wanted to know, if it's possible to replace the text "ExoPlayer Default Receiver" on the player of my TV. (See on the photo)

[image: ExoPlayer Default Receiver]

Here is the code :

```
 val media = MediaMetadata().apply {
   putString(
     MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST,
     "Artist"
   )
   putString(
     MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE,
     "Title"
   )
   putString(
     MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE,
     "Subtitle"
   )
   val cover = "Cover URL"
   val image = WebImage(Uri.Builder().encodedPath(cover).build())
   addImage(image)
}

val url = "Audio URL"
val mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Builder(url)
    .setContentType("audio/mp3")
    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
    .setContentUrl(url)
    .setMetadata(media)
    .build();

val mediaQueueItem = MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build()
val _castPlayer: CastPlayer = CastPlayer(_castContext)
_castPlayer.loadItem(mediaQueueItem, 0)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by creating my own application id and then I replaced the ExoPlayers OptionsProvider with my own OptionsProvider in the android manifest.xml

create your own chromecast application id:
https://cast.google.com/publish/#/signup
When creating your own application id you can create your own style or use the predefined one from Google. 
Follow this guide:
https://applicaster.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000721846-How-to-Obtain-a-Chromecast-App-ID
I choose Styled Media Receiver which removed "ExoPlayer Default Receiver" and instead showed my app logo

Comment: Thank you very much for your response ! I'm going to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible currently. I have filed a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156888250.

More info. There are two hardcoded titles which appear when you use the default media receiver depending on whether you use DRM:

- "Default Media Receiver" - no DRM
- "ExoPlayer Default Receiver" - with DRM